# Using an object inside of a class and using the other class' object's methods isn't working

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm trying to make a clock object by simply making an object called "boundedCounter" which has a value and a limit, the value starts at 0 and keep counting up until it reaches the limit, then it resets to 0 and continues counting. I want to have the clock object use 3 bounded counters for each seconds, minutes and hours and the rest is simple. When I did it in java, it worked pretty good. But now after learning C++, I can't seem to find why making the boundedCounter object inside of the clock class isn't working. I tried making it an inherited class, making methods and such. Here's the code:

```
class boundedCounter {
private:
    int value, limit;

public:

    boundedCounter(int boundLimit) {
        value = 0;
        limit = boundLimit;
    }

    void next() {
        if (++value == limit) {
            value = 0;
        }
    }

    void setLimit(int boundLimit) {
        limit = boundLimit;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
};

class Clock : private boundedCounter {
public:
    boundedCounter seconds(60);
    boundedCounter minutes(60);
    boundedCounter hours(24);

    seconds.setLimit(60);
};
```

Errors:

```
E0079 expected a type specifier line 35
E0079 expected a type specifier line 36
E0079 expected a type specifier line 37
E0077 this declaration has no storage class or type specifier line 39
E0065 expected a ';'
```

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? Do you get compiler errors? If yes then include them. Also without a proper [mcve] it's really hard to help you

Comment: Editing now do the minimal code needed, and adding the errors.

Comment: You are not allowed to call functions inside the class declaration, so `seconds.setLimit(60);` is not allowed (it has to be inside a member a function). And I'm not sure why you want to do this anyway, since you already set the limit during construction of the member

Comment: In the Clock class, declare the boundedCounters only like this `boundedCounter seconds;` without the limit and the parentheses. You can then set the limits of seconds, minutes and hour in the Constructor of the clock class. Also, the setLimit method should check if the value is greater than new limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in this code; First of all, there is not need to inherent from the other class! Inheritance is defined as "is a" relation. Clock isn't a bounded counter, it **has** 3 different counters - seconds, minutes, hours (thus, we have a "has a" relation). Therefore, you should change the relation to composition. **As a rule of thumb** - you should prefer *composition* over *inheritance*.

Secondly, you cannot initialize non-static member variables like that, that must be done inside non-static function (and most likely in the ctor of the class). Notice that I have put it in the initializer list, and not in the body of the ctor, which is the best practice.

The following code does compile properly:

```
class boundedCounter {
private:
    int value, limit;

public:

    boundedCounter(int boundLimit) {
        value = 0;
        limit = boundLimit;
    }

    void next() {
        if (++value == limit) {
            value = 0;
        }
    }

    void setLimit(int boundLimit) {
        limit = boundLimit;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
};

class Clock {
public:
    boundedCounter seconds;
    boundedCounter minutes;
    boundedCounter hours;

    Clock() :
    seconds(60),
    minutes(60),
    hours(24)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Pretty good explanation. Thanks. Only question I have is why did you have "seconds(60)" and not "seconds.limit = 60"? That gives me an error

Comment: Notice that limit is a *private* member of boundedCounter, therefore, I cannot use it directly (which is a good thing, since I should not change the *state* of an object not through it's API = public functions). Since the ctor does have the option to set the limit, I use it to set the limit (that should be known during the construction).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler expected in this case you declare the boundedCounter objects in class Clock following the syntax below:

```
boundedCounter seconds = 60;
boundedCounter minutes =60;
boundedCounter hours = 24;
```

The line 'seconds.setLimit(60)' won't work because it is an attempt to execution of seconds' function member on class declaration.

Furthermore, when you declare 'class Clock : private boundedCounter', you create a extended bounderCounter called Clock with the private function members next, setLimit and getValue. I'm sure it is not what you want from the class Clock to be.

Below you can check your code:

```
class boundedCounter {
private:
    int value = 0;
    int limit;

public:
    boundedCounter(int boundLimit) : limit(boundLimit) {}

    void next() {
        if (++value == limit)
            value = 0;
    }
    void setLimit(int boundLimit) { limit = boundLimit; }
    int getValue() { return value; }
};

struct Clock {
    boundedCounter seconds = 60;
    boundedCounter minutes = 60;
    boundedCounter hours = 24;
};
```

Comment: Haven't learnt about struct yet, is it better than making a new Clock class in this case?

Comment: The only difference is the default members declaration to structs is public, meanwhile it is private to classes. That means you don't need to include the word 'public:' when you declare a public member in struct. The same to word 'private:' to class.